# JQuery Datepicker 2 weeks Rage issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have following issue with JQuery date picker, have 2 fields and one bot are for dates
I would like to have date rage starting from today date and Have ability to select in future max 2 weeks. And code below is doing it, however problem is when you first access 2nd field, first one have all the available dates from today not only 2 weeks in the future and then if you fiddle a little with fields all the dates are available in 1st fields from the past. Please help

[PLEASE EXAMPLE on FIDDLE CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tpx9X/2/)

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

    $( "#from" ).datetimepicker({                   
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",               
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      minDate: -0,
      maxDate: "+2w",
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );

      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datetimepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: "+2w",
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Fields below

```
<input style="text-transform:none;"  class="button_date"  type="text" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['from']; ?>" size="15"  id="from" name="from" readonly />
 <input style="text-transform:none;"  class="button_date"  size="15" type="text" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['to']; ?>" id="to" name="to" readonly />
```

Comment: What are the intial values you are setting ($_REQUEST['from'] and $_REQUEST['to'])?

Comment: ok, I set up a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tpx9X/ but I don't quite understand what the problem is, could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was when you are playing around your two fields and toDate is empty, from date max defaults to max date to pick from. Make a check for if toField is not empty and is valid.
Update JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tpx9X/16/)
I added check onClose event of toField.

```
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 2,
          minDate: 0,
          maxDate: "+2w",
          onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
             if (selectedDate !== 'toField' && selectedDate.length > 0){
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
             }
          }
     });
```